# How to call same service instance from multiple activities in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've just started looking into Xamarin and just can not to wrap around my head how to make multiple Activities have a reference same instance of service.

I am starting `KeyPressedReceiver` from `MainActivity` and start listening for power button being pressed.

When three click are being made, I am calling service method `InitCancelActivity`, which starts playing mp3 file and opens `CancelActivity`.

In `CancelActivity` there is a text field and a button. And when user press this button, I want the value from text field to be passes  to the `GeneralService` method `KillAlert`.

The question is how to reference instance of `GeneralService` (which is already created) from `CancelActivity`, so I could call `KillAlert`?

And this part

```
if (_service == null)
    _service = new GeneralService();
```

looks absolutely wrong. Should I instantiate it in `MainActivity` and pass to a `KeyPressedReceiver` constructor?

```
[Activity(Label = "TTTT", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    KeyPressedReceiver receiver;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        receiver = new KeyPressedReceiver();
        RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionScreenOn));
    }
}


[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class KeyPressedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private GeneralService _service;
    private int _clicks = 0;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         if (_service == null)
            _service = new GeneralService();

        _clicks++;

        if (_clicks > 5)
        {
            _service.InitCancelActivity();
        }
    }
}


[Service(Name = "com.ff.GeneralService")]
public class GeneralService : Service {
    private readonly Android.Media.MediaPlayer _player;

    public GeneralService()
    {
        _player = new Android.Media.MediaPlayer(); 
    }

    public void RaiseAlert()
    {
        // start playing .mp3 file
    }

    public void KillAlert(string pass)
    {
        // stop playing .mp3 file
    }

    public void InitCancelActivity()
    {
        this.RaiseAlert();

        var i = new Intent(this, typeof(CancelActivity));
        i.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        this.StartActivity(i);
    }
}

[Activity(Label = "CancelActivity")]
public class CancelActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.cancel);

        this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.cancelButtonYes).Click += delegate
        {
            var password = this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.cancelPassword);

            // call KillAlert method from GeneralServic
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create static GeneralService instance and use in Cancel Activity.
for example

```
[Service(Name = "com.ff.GeneralService")]
public class GeneralService : Service {
    private readonly Android.Media.MediaPlayer _player;
    public static generalService;
    public GeneralService()
    {
        _player = new Android.Media.MediaPlayer(); 
         generalService=this
    }

    public void RaiseAlert()
    {
        // start playing .mp3 file
    }

    public void KillAlert(string pass)
    {
        // stop playing .mp3 file
    }

    public void InitCancelActivity()
    {
        this.RaiseAlert();

        var i = new Intent(this, typeof(CancelActivity));
        i.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        this.StartActivity(i);
    }
}
```

and use in CancelActivity like below example

```
[Activity(Label = "CancelActivity")]
public class CancelActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.cancel);

        this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.cancelButtonYes).Click += delegate
        {
            var password = this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.cancelPassword);

            // call KillAlert method from GeneralServic
          GeneralService.generalService.KillAlert(password.TEXT);

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I have now, but for some reason it does seem to be wrong. But it's maybe just me